# What is the minimum number of doors to a laboratory that would satisfy these conditions?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, puzzle

$S$ scientists are working in a lab that they want to keep secure. They want to install $D$ doors to the lab, such that each door has $L$ locks that each require a different key to open. The scientists want any group of $L$ or more scientists to be able to open all of the locks on at least one door (any group of $L-1$ or fewer scientists cannot enter the lab). To do so, each scientist is given one key to a lock for ever door. For some $S$ and $L$, what is the minimum number of doors $D$ required to satisfy these conditions?

For $L=1$, $D$ is trivially $1$, and for $L=2$, $D=\lceil \log_{2}{S}\rceil$ seems to be the best solution. What might a solution for $L=3$ (or more generally any $L$) look like?

(I had originally seen this question asked for a specific case of $S=8$ and $L=4$.)

Comment: 1) Are we allowed to give 2 scientists the same key? 2) Can you explain why we have "To do so, each scientist is given one key to a lock for ever door. "?

Comment: 1) Two different scientists can both be given the same key $k_{i, j}$ to lock $l_{i, j}$ on door $d_i$.
2) If there are doors $D = \{d_1, d_2, ..., d_D\}$, each scientist $s$ is given a set of keys $\{k_{1, s_1}, k_{2, s_2}, ..., k_{D, s_D}\}$.
Sorry for not clarifying these points better.

Comment: (To clarify my comment) The condition of "any group of L-1 cannot enter the lab" seems redundant since there are L locks on every door, and these scientists only have L-1 keys relevant to this door.  Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Ah yes - this condition is redundant given that the scientists would only have $L-1$ keys to the door.

Comment: I suspect a general formula doesn't exist. I'm believe that for $ S = 8, L = 4$, we have $D=5$.